# Gerando Script e salvando em uma pasta específica?

Tags: visual-studio, migrations

Olhando um exemplo de como [Gerar scripts SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#generate-sql-scripts).

Então executei o comando a seguir:

```
PM> Script-Migration
```

O comando acima funciona bem, porem quero salvar em uma pasta específica, tentei dessa forma:

```
PM> Script-Migration -OutputDir Areas/Identity/Data/Migrations/Script.sql
```

Recebo erro:

> Não é possível localizar um parâmetro que coincida com o nome de
>   parâmetro 'OutputDir'.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Tente utilizar `Add-Migration` ao invés de `Script-Migration`. Pela documentação comando script não aceita o `-OutputDir`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode obter a informação detalhada com comando:

```
get-help Script-Migration -detailed
```

Para gerar script e salvar em uma pasta específica, executa o comando a seguir:

```
Script-Migration -Output Project/Areas/Identity/Data/Script.sql
```